# Doctrine2 returns array of 1 element instead of null

Tags: mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get top 3 users who has featured property = true. Here's my EntityRepository:

```
public function getFeaturedCleaners()
{
    $baseQuery = $this->_baseCleanerQuery();

    return $baseQuery
        ->where($baseQuery->expr()->eq('c.featured', $baseQuery->expr()->literal(true)))
        ->andWhere($baseQuery->expr()->isNotNull('c.user'))
        ->orderBy('ratingTotal', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(3)
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}

private function _baseCleanerQuery()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select([
            'c as user',
            'COALESCE(AVG(rv.speed), 0) as ratingSpeed',
            'COALESCE(AVG(rv.quality), 0) as ratingQuality',
            'COALESCE(AVG(rv.responsibility), 0) as ratingResponsibility',
            'COALESCE((AVG(rv.speed) + AVG(rv.quality) + AVG(rv.responsibility)) / 3, 0) as ratingTotal',
        ])
        ->leftJoin('c.reviews', 'rv');
}
```

But when there's no featured users, I get one row with null fields, instead of empty array:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["user"]=> NULL ["ratingSpeed"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["ratingQuality"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["ratingResponsibility"]=> string(6) "0.0000" ["ratingTotal"]=> string(10) "0.00000000" } }
```

Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using aggregation in your query (with AVG), so it always will get at least a row with the result.

```
SELECT AVG(0) FROM user WHERE 0;
```

This query will always return at least 1 row with the result, not a `null` result.

If the query must continue as it is, you can filter the result before return it checking that the user is not null, otherwise return an empty array.

```
return (null == $result[0]['user'] ? [] : $result);
```